# Wrong value in array which contains instances of a class (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, instance

I use an array to create instances of a class.

I declared them in the Header file:

```
Figure *soldier;
Fight *weapon;
```

In the cpp I use the following code to create it:

```
std::cout << "How many soldier? ";
std::cin >> i_soldier;
std::cout << "How many weapon? ";
std::cin >> i_weapon;

soldier= new Figure[i_soldier];
weapon = new Fight[i_weapon];
```

The class Figure has this constructor:

```
Figure::Figure()
{
    position = 0;
}
```

When I'm running the code it compiles fine, but when I look the position at the begin, the last array entry has a wrong value; I guess it points at a value from a memory address. All the other entries have the value 0.

This is how I say which instance I want to go.

```
    for(int i = 0; i <= i_soldier; i++)
    {
        soldier[i].position();
    }
```

Does anybody know where the error can come from?

Comment: That's one looked up too much: `for(int i = 0; i <= i_soldier; i++)` you change this to `for(int i = 0; i < i_soldier; i++)`.

Comment: You should not define soldier and weapon in your .h, just declare them and define in the .cpp

Comment: Use vectors which are bounds checked in good debug compilers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers, its working now. So stupid error...

Answer (score 4):

Arrays are 0-indexed, the last position of the array is `i_soldier-1`, change your condition to a strict `<`.